# How to get creation time of file (& other properties) that is archived inside tar?

Tags: c++, windows, winapi, visual-c++, tar

### I am writing a code in c++ using VS 2010 and Win32 to simply extract TAR files.

I have implemented the algorithm completely from scratch to do the extraction.

I have a TAR header structure like this:

```
/* tar Header Block, from POSIX 1003.1-1990.  */

/* POSIX header.  */

struct posix_header
{                              /* byte offset */
  char name[100];               /*   0 */
  char mode[8];                 /* 100 */
  char uid[8];                  /* 108 */
  char gid[8];                  /* 116 */
  char size[12];                /* 124 */
  char mtime[12];               /* 136 */
  char chksum[8];               /* 148 */
  char typeflag;                /* 156 */
  char linkname[100];           /* 157 */
  char magic[6];                /* 257 */
  char version[2];              /* 263 */
  char uname[32];               /* 265 */
  char gname[32];               /* 297 */
  char devmajor[8];             /* 329 */
  char devminor[8];             /* 337 */
  char prefix[155];             /* 345 */
                                /* 500 */
};
```

From the structure I am able to retain modified time stamp of file using mtime[12].
And then I use the Win32 ::SetFileTime() function to update the time stamp properties of extracted file.

**But the problem is in accessing the created file time and last access  time.**

> Can anyone help me to find out where this info is stored inside TAR header???
>
> And also how will I be able to decode file permissions like Read-Only, Hidden, System.. for Windows???

Answer (score 2, accepted):

TAR file format is a Unix invention and so the file info it stores does not always map well onto Windows conventions.

The creation and access time are not stored in the standard TAR format, so you need to either leave them to defaults, or set to the same value as modification time. However, it's possible that you actually have an [ustar format](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ustar#UStar_format) file, which does add a possibility to store such information in the extended file entries. See [here](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/manual/html_chapter/Tar-Internals.html) for more details.

The Unix permission are stored in the `mode` field as [an octal number](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_permissions#Numeric_notation) . There is no direct equivalent of those to Windows file attributes, so about the only thing you can do is to set Read-only attribute if they don't include the "w" permission.

Comment: The link which you shared I had visited before and didn't refer it because in /* Jörg Schilling star header */ prefix field is again split into prefix, atime, & ctime which I think is meaningless.

Comment: This utility [www.gnu.org/software/tar](http://www.gnu.org/software/tar/) when I tried shows different creation time and modified time after extraction. Don't know what they have used...